# Как сохранить на компьютер фото, отправленное пользователем?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пользователь отправляет фото боту. Как сохранить
на компьютер фото (с помощью библиотеки `aiogram`)?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def handle_docs_photo(message):

    raw = await message.photo[0].download()
    b = BytesIO()
    b.write(raw.raw)
    with open('testfile.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def handle_docs_photo(message):

    await message.photo[-1].download('test.jpg')
```